# Observer node with confidential identities

Tags: corda

I've started making some tests with the Observer node (https://docs.corda.net/tutorial-observer-nodes.html), and I just built the following simple scenario:

1. Regulator issues 10.POUNDS to Bank A (CashIssueAndPaymentFlow)
2. Bank A sends 4.POUNDS to Bank B using confidential identities (CashPaymentFlow, anonymous=true)
3. In a subflow, Bank A syncs identities (IdentitySyncFlow) and reports the transaction (SendTransactionFlow) to the Regulator

When I query the Regulator vault, it can't identify Bank B as the owner of the 4.POUNDS, that is, it cannot resolve the identity using wellKnownPartyFromAnonymous():

```
6.00 GBP, owner=C=BR,L=Sao Paulo,O=BankA
4.00 GBP, owner=Anonymous(DLEg4Kqd7dwcGqkMrJEWoxugT61SoYKzxqpcMBKbMGXu3q)
```

Maybe I'm missing something?

> Follow the code:
>
> ```
> object TransferCashFlow {
>
>     @InitiatingFlow
>     @StartableByRPC
>     class Initiator(val amount: Amount<Currency>, val otherParty: Party, val regulator: Party) : FlowLogic<SignedTransaction>() {
>
>             @Suspendable
>             override fun call(): SignedTransaction {
>                 val tx = subFlow(CashPaymentFlow(amount, otherParty, true)).stx
>                 subFlow(ReportFlow.Initiator(regulator, tx))
>                 return tx
>             }
>     }
> }
>
> object ReportFlow {
>
>     @InitiatingFlow
>     class Initiator(val regulator: Party, val tx: SignedTransaction) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
>
>         @Suspendable
>         override fun call() {
>
>             val regulatorSession = initiateFlow(regulator)
>             subFlow(IdentitySyncFlow.Send(regulatorSession, tx.tx))
>             subFlow(SendTransactionFlow(regulatorSession, tx))
>         }
>     }
>
>     @InitiatedBy(Initiator::class)
>     class Responder(private val otherPartySession: FlowSession) : FlowLogic<Unit>() {
>         @Suspendable
>         override fun call() {
>
>             subFlow(IdentitySyncFlow.Receive(otherPartySession))
>             subFlow(ReceiveTransactionFlow(otherPartySession, true, StatesToRecord.ALL_VISIBLE))
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: So you never sync identities between Bank B and the regulator?

Comment: No. In the scenario above, could I just collect the certificates based on the transanction inputs/outputs and send them explicily to the regulator (from bank A)?

Comment: That sounds error-prone :) . What happens if after sending the transaction to the regulator, you get the regulator to call `IdentitySyncFlow`. Does that allow the regulator to retrieve Bank B's identity?

Comment: First, I'd check to see whether Bank A has the certificate for Bank B's public key. Assuming it does, then Bank A should be able to forward on the certificate to the regulator via the identity sync flow. It would be useful to see a minimised example of your code. Cheers!

Comment: This actually isn't the case - `IdentitySyncFlow` explicitly only sends the *sending node's* confidential identities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design, `IdentitySyncFlow.Send` will **only** send across the certificates for the confidential identities in the transaction that belong to the sending node. See the definition of `extractOurConfidentialIdentities()` in `IdentitySyncFlow`:

```
private fun extractOurConfidentialIdentities(): Map<AbstractParty, PartyAndCertificate?> {
    val states: List<ContractState> = (tx.inputs.map { serviceHub.loadState(it) }.requireNoNulls().map { it.data } + tx.outputs.map { it.data })
    val identities: Set<AbstractParty> = states.flatMap(ContractState::participants).toSet()
    // Filter participants down to the set of those not in the network map (are not well known)
    val confidentialIdentities = identities
        .filter { serviceHub.networkMapCache.getNodesByLegalIdentityKey(it.owningKey).isEmpty() }
        .toList()
    return confidentialIdentities
        .map { Pair(it, serviceHub.identityService.certificateFromKey(it.owningKey)) }
        // Filter down to confidential identities of our well known identity
        // TODO: Consider if this too restrictive - we perhaps should be checking the name on the signing certificate in the certificate path instead
        .filter { it.second?.name == ourIdentity.name }
        .toMap()
}
```

The penultimate line ensures that the node doesn't send any identity certificates that aren't its own. This is to prevent a node tricking a counterparty into sending it a bunch of confidential identities.

If you wanted to send **all** the confidential identities, you'd have to define your own flow, based on `IdentitySyncFlow`, which doesn't perform this filtering.

Comment: Hi @joel. I edited the original post with the code. Even Bank A using IdentitySyncFlow explicitly, the regulator node is not able to resolve Bank B identity.

Comment: Thanks, looking into it.

Comment: Apologies, I was wrong - I've updated my answer above.